# <td> content displays as plain text, when I use data-toggle="table"

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to use bootstrap `data-toggle="table"`, but when I enable it, it starts to render all content in `<td>` as plain text (ignoring tags).

[image]

My code looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Bootstrap : CRUD Table</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Varela+Round'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.css">
<script src="extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.0/bootstrap-table.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://rawgit.com/vitalets/x-editable/master/dist/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-table.css">

<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-table.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-table-zh-CN.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="table-wrapper">
    
<table id="table" class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive"
             data-toggle="table"
             data-filter-control="true" 
             data-click-to-select="true">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name1</th>
            <th>Name2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td data-toggle="modal">     
            <p>My Text Here</p>
            </td>
            <td data-toggle="modal">     
            <p>My Text Here</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        
    </tbody>
</table>

<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script  src="./script.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.0/bootstrap-table.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.9.1/extensions/editable/bootstrap-table-editable.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.9.1/extensions/export/bootstrap-table-export.js'></script>
<script src='https://rawgit.com/hhurz/tableExport.jquery.plugin/master/tableExport.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.9.1/extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Everything works as usual, when I remove data-toggle="table"

Comment: I can see tags, not a plain text. Can you please explain it a little bit more what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to render tags in ``<td>`` as usial html markup. But somewhy it just show it as a text inside of a table when I use data-toggle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Just added "data-escape="false"" in table definition.

https://codepen.io/shubham-sharma-the-looper/pen/KKaMWGL

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Bootstrap : CRUD Table</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Varela+Round'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.css">
<script src="extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.0/bootstrap-table.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://rawgit.com/vitalets/x-editable/master/dist/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-table.css">

<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-table.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-table-zh-CN.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="table-wrapper">
    
<table id="table" class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive"
             data-toggle="table"
             data-filter-control="true" 
             data-click-to-select="true" data-escape="false">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name1</th>
            <th>Name2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td data-toggle="modal">     
            <p>My Text Here</p>
            </td>
            <td data-toggle="modal">     
            <p>My Text Here</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        
    </tbody>
</table>

<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script  src="./script.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.0/bootstrap-table.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.9.1/extensions/editable/bootstrap-table-editable.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.9.1/extensions/export/bootstrap-table-export.js'></script>
<script src='https://rawgit.com/hhurz/tableExport.jquery.plugin/master/tableExport.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.9.1/extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I see html when I run your code not a plain text.

Comment: Because i did not send header with refs. In this snippet it just ignores unknown properties and renders normally.

Comment: Update: add head